# Using Spark-Submit to write to S3 in "local" mode using S3A Directory Committer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, hdfs

I'm currently running PySpark via local mode. I want to be able to efficiently output parquet files to S3 via the [S3 Directory Committer](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/bk_cloud-data-access/content/s3-introducing-committers.html). This PySpark instance is using the local disk, not HDFS, as it is being submitted via `spark-submit --master local[*]`.

I can successfully write to my S3 Instance without enabling the directory committer. However, this involves writing staging files to S3 and renaming them, which is slow and unreliable. I would like for Spark to write to my local filesystem as a temporary store, and then copy to S3.

I have the following configuration in my PySpark conf:

```
self.spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
self.spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name", "directory")
self.spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass", "org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.PathOutputCommitProtocol")
self.spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class", "org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.BindingParquetOutputCommitter")
```

My spark-submit command looks like this:

```
spark-submit --master local[*] --py-files files.zip --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.375,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0,org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.PathOutputCommitProtocol --driver-memory 4G --name clean-raw-recording_data main.py
```

`spark-submit` gives me the following error, due to the requisite JAR not being in place:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.PathOutputCommitProtocol
```

My questions are:

1. Which JAR (specifically, the maven coordinates) do I need to include in `spark-submit --packages` in order to be able to reference `PathOutputCommitProtocol`?
2. Once I have (1) working, will I be able to use PySpark's local mode to stage temporary files on the local filesystem? Or is HDFS a strict requirement?

I need this to be running in local mode, not cluster mode.

**EDIT:**

I got this to work with the following configuration:
Using `pyspark` version `3.1.2` and the package

`org.apache.spark:spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12:3.1.1.3.1.7270.0-253`.

I needed to add the cloudera repository using the `--repositories` option for `spark-submit`:

```
spark-submit --repositories https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/ --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.375,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0,org.apache.spark:spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12:3.1.1.3.1.7270.0-253
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you need the spark-hadoop-cloud module for the release of spark you are using
2. the committer is happy using the local fs (it's now the public integration test suites work https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/cloud-integration. all that's needed is a "real" filesystem shared across all workers and the spark driver, so the driver gets the manifests of each pending commit.
3. print the _SUCCESS file after a job to see what the committer did: 0 byte file == old committer, JSON with diagnostics == new one

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! I'm currently using `pyspark==3.1.2`, which version of `spark-hadoop-cloud` do I need to use? Is it `3.1.2` as well? I'm currently looking here at the available JARs - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hadoop-cloud?repo=cloudera-repos

Comment: yes, you must have a 100% consistent set of spark- artifacts f

Comment: @GauthamAcharya Regarding the compatible version I can say that using spark-hadoop-cloud 3.1.1.3.1.7270.0-253 with spark 3.1.1 does work. Can't say for sure about spark 3.1.2 though

Comment: I got this to work - I'm using `pyspark` version `3.1.2` and used the package `org.apache.spark:spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12:3.1.1.3.1.7270.0-253`.

I needed to add the cloudera repository using the `--repositories` option for `spark-submit`:

`--repositories https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/ --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.375,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0,org.apache.spark:spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12:3.1.1.3.1.7270.0-253
`